# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined when property exists

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm getting this error when console.log(likes)

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'likeCount' of undefined

```
newState.images[action.data]
```

console logs an object

```
{
  "id": 26,
  "image_title": "a",
  "img_url": "h*********,
  "created_at": "2019-08-24T17:16:47.116Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-08-24T17:16:47.116Z",
  "user_id": 1,
  "likeCount": "1",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "googleId": null,
    "username": "******",
    "password": "**********,
    "email": "*********",
    "created_at": "2019-08-23T21:14:22.356Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-23T21:14:22.356Z"
  },
  "comments": []
}
```

My main objective is to increment/decrement likeCount value in reducer.

this is the reducer. What should i do to the reducer case that will allow me to increment or decrement value. As of now, likeCount does exist but console.log is showing the opposite.

```
import {
  UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
  DELETE_IMAGE_FAILURE,
  FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT,
  POST_LIKE,
  POST_LIKE_SUCCESS,
  DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
  DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
} from '../types';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
const initialState = {
  images: [],
  allIds:[],
  byId:{},
  likeCount: {},
};

const allIds = (state = initialState.allIds, action ) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
        return action.images.reduce( (nextState, image) => {
          if(nextState.indexOf(image.id) === -1){
            nextState.push(image.id)
          }
          return nextState;

        }, [...state])
    case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action)
        return [action.data.id, ...state];
    case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
        const newState = {...state};  // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
        const likes = newState[action.data].likeCount
       return likes - 1

      default:
        return state
  }
}

const byId = (state = initialState.byId, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return action.images.reduce( (nextState, image) => {
          nextState[image.id] = image;
          return nextState;
      }, {...state})

    case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.data)
      // what if i want to refer to action.data[key], how would i do this ?
         return {
        ...state,
        [action.data.id]: action.data
      };
      case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
        // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
        const newState = {...state};  // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
        const likes = newState[action.data].likeCount
       return likes - 1
      default:
        return state
  }
}


export default combineReducers({
  allIds,
  byId,
});


export const getAllImages = (state) => {
  const { allIds, byId } = state;
  const posts = allIds.map(id => byId[id])
  console.log(posts)
  return posts
}
```

error at allIds

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to set the state to `initialState.allIds`? because in `case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS` you try to access the `images` attribute thats in `initialState` but not in `state` as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the "**likeCount**" from `newState[action.data]`. Can you please debug the code check the value of `newState[action.data]`. I think it's undefined.

Comment: i updated my code as well, the error still persists. Sorry about that.

Comment: You mentioned the log for `newState.images[action.data]` not for `newState[action.data]`.

Comment: Okay let me check the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the code. Sorry about that. The error still persists.

Comment: Clue i made a mistake its supposed to be `newState[action.data] ` sorry about that. i got confused. so for sure newState[action.data] renders the object for sure.

Comment: despite newState[action.data] console.loging an object. likeCount still shows undefined.

Comment: Are you getting an error in which function `allIds` or `byId`?

Comment: getting the error in the reducer not the function. AllIds and ByIds gets the image posts

Comment: i attached an image.

Comment: Can you please add two console logs `console.log(newState); console.log(action.data);`  in **allIds** function above the `const likes = newState[action.data].likeCount` line.

Answer (score 0):

Different potential problem: `case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:` is supposed to return the entire new state, not just that one value.

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an
>   action, and returns the next state.
>   https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

I think you want something like `return {...state, likeCount: likes - 1}` here
https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator

Comment: @BARNOWL yes, edited. Coud you please answer my comment or explain why you are doing `state = initialState.allIds`? This seems a bit confusing and would recommend just passing in `state=initialState` if you are confused

Comment: thanks for your help, i have to restructure the reducer. I will make a new answer if i run into an issue.